# GCP windows VM does not work when logged off

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server

I am running a Windows Server VM on GCP.
When logging in via Remote Desktop, I am starting certain applications which should actively run for a couple of hours.
But when closing my Remote Desktop Connection, all applications stop working.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the session ongoing, you'll have to configure the RD Session Host time limits.
Open the group policy editor with: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `gpedit.msc`, confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then in the management console, navigate to:

- `Computer Configuration`
- `Administrative Templates`
- `Windows Components`
- `Remote Desktop Services`
- `Remote Desktop Session Host`
- `Session Time Limits`

There one can adjust the settings:

- Set time limit for disconnected sessions
- Terminate session when time limits are reached